# Bat file replace character

Tags: batch-file

I use bat script to backup MySQl database

```
SET SOURCEDIR="C:\Program Files\MariaDB\data\"

set now=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%

for /d %%i in (%SOURCEDIR%\*) do (
if not "%%~ni"=="temp" "C:\Program Files\MariaDB\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -c -e -q  --single-transaction=TRUE %%~ni | "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -si"%%~ni_%now%.sql" "D:\backup\SQL\%now%\%%~ni.sql.7z"
)
exit
```

But if database have dot in name, for exapmle data.2023, then MariDB create folder data@002e2023
So SQL dump is empty.
How can I replace @002e to . in this script here *single-transaction=TRUE %%~ni | *?

%%~ni:@002e=!.!% is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your attempt, `%%~ni:@002e=!.!%`, I'd assume you need to create a variable, and delay variable expansion to use it.

Example:

```bash
@Set "SOURCEDIR=%ProgramFiles%\MariaDB\data"
@Set "now=%DATE%"
@Set "now=%now:~-4%-%now:~-7,2%-%now:~-10,2%"
@For /D %%G In ("%SOURCEDIR%\*") Do @If /I Not "%%~nxG" == "temp" (
    Set "dirname=%%~nxG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    "%ProgramFiles%\MariaDB\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -c -e -q --single-transaction=TRUE !dirname:@002e=.!^
     | "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -si"%%~nxG_%now%.sql" "D:\backup\SQL\%now%\%%~nxG.sql.7z"
    EndLocal)
```